# How to draw a circle with a 3D effect to it?

Tags: opengl, 3d, geometry

I'm building a game and it consists mainly of a network. The nodes are going to be circles (so far I've done those), but I need them to have a 3D effect to them. Like these:

[3D circles](http://community.calrec.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/netwrk.png)

I tought maybe this can be accomplished with textures? I've never used textures before. Or maybe changing my 2D world to 3D and then cast a light? But this would change every other object.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

> Or maybe changing my 2D world to 3D

Depends on your target GPUs' capabilities (however if you don't want to support anything built before 2005 you're in the clear): You can use a fragment shader to fake a sphere on a quad

Here's a nice tutorial on how to do it: http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Illumination/Tutorial%2013.html

> and then cast a light? But this would change every other object.

OpenGL is not a scene graph, it's a sequential drawing API. You can turn off and on OpenGL state (like the shaders used) arbitrarily and selectively.